# What do you call a player on whom his or her team depends?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

This athlete is very good at what he or she does. The coach counts on him/her.  He's like the *trustee* of the game.

Comment: For single-word requests, we generally like to see an example sentence. This question is likely to be closed if you don't give us one.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the most common word for this is the **star** player.

For a less common word, in the US we often call this a **franchise player**, especially in pro sports. The idea is, these are the players that make the team what it is (and the teams are, in some sense, franchised from the league).

I believe the usage started when some pro leagues introduced new teams, they'd allow the new teams to *draft* some players from existing teams, but they'd allow the existing teams to protect their best players as *franchise players*.

Answer (score 1):

The **go-to guy**.

At least that's what reporters like to call such athletes.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the person the '**MVP**' or '**Most Valuable Player**'.

This is normally an award that is given to players at the end of the game.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_Valuable_Player

Answer (score 1):

The term I've always heard used is ***linchpin***.  From the Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> ***[linchpin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/linchpin)***
> (also **lynchpin**)
>
> **noun**
>
> 1. A person or thing vital to an enterprise or organization.
>    *‘nurses are the linchpin of the National Health Service’*

Writing about various historian's opinion of [George Washington's role in the American revolution](https://www.edwardlengel.com/was-george-washington-indispensable/), Edward Lengel wrote:

> For Don Higginbotham, he was the “**Linchpin**” of the Revolution.

The San Mateo County Historical Society had this [description of athelete Peter Tuipulotu](http://historysmc.pastperfectonline.com/byperson?keyword=Tuipulotu%2C%20Peter):

> Few prep athletes dominated the San Mateo County sporting scene in the mid-1980's more than Peter Tuipulotu. His Bearcat football teams ran off a 27-game winning streak. And he was the **linchpin** of those standout ballclubs.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I was in high school, "football manager" games were really popular. Although I didn't like them, I gave it a go. I remember when I wanted to transfer somebody to my team sometimes the coach of the other team would object and say;

"xxx is an **indispensable** member of the team".

It means "absolutely necessary". That player is absolutely needed, cannot be let go to any other team or cannot stay on side.

Answer (score -1):

...a player **on whom their team depends?**

I'd say they are the player who can **single-handedly secure victory** for their team.

> From the web:
>
> - Miskelly, who missed all of last season with a serious ankle injury, made a succession of saves to almost single handedly secure victory.
> - Kohli produced two sparkling innings of 167 and 81 in the second Test to assert India's dominance again and single-handedly secure victory.